# Set Theory Union of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

There are 3 operations with sets in mathematics: intersection, difference and union (unification). In PHP we can do this operations with arrays:

- intersection: `array_intersect`
- difference: `array_diff`

**What function is for union?**

No duplicates can be in the result array (like `array_intersect` and `array_diff`).

If indexes are numeric then `array_merge` will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended ([PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Try `array_merge`:

```
array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));
```

[PHP Manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: I don't understand why this is accepted and upvoted more than the answers pointing out the union operator (+). Am I missing something about the union operator?

Comment: PHP's "union operator" does not perform a mathematical union. var_dump([1,2]+[3,4]) has the mathematical union of [1,2,3,4] (due to 4 values), but the two arrays only have two unique keys, therefore the script will output [1,2]. PHP's "union" operator is totally unrelated to a mathematical union

Comment: Note that array_unique won't reindex the keys for numeric arrays - you may need to use `array_values` as well if the array indexes need to be sequential.

Comment: @JoshRibakoff PHP's union operator is a mathematical union of the array's keys, not its values.  It is certainly not "totally unrelated" to a mathematical union.  You can use `array_flip` to put the values in the keys so the array union operator applies - see my answer.

Comment: Beware that this will not work if the input arrays contain string keys.  For example:
`php -r 'var_dump(array_unique(array_merge(["a"=>"cat","b"=>"dog"], ["b"=>"cow","c"=>"hen"])));'`
produces ['cat','cow','hen'] because values with the same string key are overwritten.  To avoid this problem, call array_values on each input array before merging, as follows:
`php -r 'var_dump(array_unique(array_merge(array_values(["a"=>"cat","b"=>"dog"]), array_values(["b"=>"cow","c"=>"hen"]))));'`

Comment: The matches the top comment from the PHP: Array Operators documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php#86379, which is taken from the "Programming PHP" O'Reilly book by Rasmus Ledorf.

Comment: Warning: a php array is not a mathematical set, it only makes sense to talk about a union OF KEYS or a union OF VALUES in the context of php, the full set of (key,val) pairs is not necessarily preserved by a merge [but, and this is tricky, it will be if all the keys in both arrays are unique].

Answer (score 11):

`array_unique( array_merge( ... ) )`

Answer (score 11):

Adrien's answer won't necessary produce a sequentially numbered array from two sequentially numbered arrays - here are some options that will:

```
array_values(array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2)));
```

(Adrien's answer with renumbering the keys afterward)

```
array_keys(array_flip($array1)+array_flip($array2))
```

(Put the values in the keys, and use the array union operator)

```
array_merge($array1, array_diff($array2, $array1))
```

(Remove the shared values from the second array before merging)

Benchmark results (for merging two arrays of length 1000 a thousand times on my system):

- Unique (Adrien's version): 2.862163066864 seconds
- Values_Unique: 3.12 seconds
- Keys_Flip: 2.34 seconds
- Merge_Diff: 2.64 seconds

Same test, but with the two arrays being very similar (at least 80% duplicate):

- Unique (Adrien's version): 2.92 seconds
- Values_Unique: 3.15 seconds
- Keys_Flip: 1.84 seconds
- Merge_Diff: 2.36 seconds

It seems using the array union operator to do the actual union is the fastest method.  Note however that `array_flip` is only safe if the array's values are all strings or all integers; if you have to produce the union of an array of objects, I recommend the version with `array_merge` and `array_diff`.

Answer (score 6):

use "+" operator to do so. See the link [Array Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

Comment: @GordonM It's awkward because the `+` operator is defined as being the array union. You're right that it does a union of keys, but it [chooses the first array over the second when removing duplicates](https://softonsofa.com/php-array_merge-vs-array_replace-vs-plus-aka-union/) which is the opposite of `array_merge`.

Comment: Actually this answer is just a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/10485300/327074 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/10485348/327074

Answer (score 5):

Use `array_unique` and `array_merge` together.

Answer (score 4):

From the code in the [PHP: Array Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) documentation:

```
<?php
$a = array("a" => "apple", "b" => "banana");
$b = array("a" => "pear", "b" => "strawberry", "c" => "cherry");

$c = $a + $b; // Union of $a and $b
echo "Union of \$a and \$b: \n";
var_dump($c);

$c = $b + $a; // Union of $b and $a
echo "Union of \$b and \$a: \n";
var_dump($c);
?>
```

When executed, this script will print the following:

```
Union of $a and $b:
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(5) "apple"
  ["b"]=>
  string(6) "banana"
  ["c"]=>
  string(6) "cherry"
}
Union of $b and $a:
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(4) "pear"
  ["b"]=>
  string(10) "strawberry"
  ["c"]=>
  string(6) "cherry"
}
```

Comment: From the [top comment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php#86379) on the [PHP: Array Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) documentation. *"The union operator did not behave as I thought it would on first glance. It implements a union (of sorts) based on the keys of the array, not on the values."* He then goes on to suggest `array_unique(array_merge($a,$b))`

Comment: I've added the link, but if you are going to copy and paste directly from the PHP source code you should add in a reference.

Answer (score 2):

The OP did not specify whether the union is by **value** or by **key** and PHP has `array_merge` for merging values and `+` for merging the keys. The results depends on whether the array is indexed or keyed **and** which array comes first.

```php
$a = ['a', 'b'];
$b = ['b', 'c'];

$c = ['a' => 'A',  'b' => 'B'];
‌‌$d = ['a' => 'AA', 'c' => 'C'];
```

### Indexed array

See [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

#### By value using `array_merge`

```php
‌‌array_merge($a, $b); // [‌0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c']
‌‌array_merge($b, $a); // ‌[0 => 'b', 1 => 'c', 2 => 'a', 3 => 'b']
```

#### merge by key using `+` operator

See [`+` operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

```php
‌‌$a + $b; ‌// [0 => 'a', 1 => 'b']
$b + $a; // [0 => 'b', 1 => 'c']
```

### Keyed array

#### By value using `array_merge`

```php
‌array_merge($c, $d); // ‌['a' => 'AA', 'b' => 'B', 'c' => 'C']
array_merge($d, $c); // ['a' => 'A',  'c' => 'C', 'b' => 'B']
```

#### merge by key using `+` operator

```php
$c + $d; // [‌'a' => 'A',  'b' => 'B', 'c' => 'C']
‌‌$d + $c; // ‌['a' => 'AA', 'c' => 'C', 'b' => 'B']
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator:

```
$x[0] = 4;
$x[1] = 1;

$y[0] = 9;
$y[2] = 5;

$u = $y + $x;

// Results in:
$u[0] === 9;
$u[1] === 1;
$u[2] === 5;
```

Note that `$x + $y` != `$y + $x`

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($first, $second);
```

can be useful when you have arrays with arrays inside.

Answer (score 0):

Just use   `$array1 + $array2`
It will result union of both array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
function array_union($array1, $array2){
    return array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));
}
```