# How to merge two arrays by its values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

What I need is really simple:

I have two arrays like that:

```
<?php
$a1 = [1,2,3];
$a2 = [2,3,4];
```

I need to combine them so that the result is:

```
$result = [1,2,3,4];
```

I've tried `array_merge` but the result was `[1,2,3,2,3,4]`

Comment: [array_merge()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), [array_unique()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) and optionally [sort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Comment: Try `print_r(array_unique(array_merge($a1, $a2)));`. Once you merge you need to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an answer to this here: [Set Theory Union of arrays in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485242/union-of-arrays-in-php)

By expanding on your current method. You can call `array_unique` and `sort` on the resulting array.

```
$a = [1,2,3];
$b = [2,3,4];
$result = array_merge($a, $b);
$result = array_unique($result);
sort($result);
```

This will result in:

```
array(4) {
    [0] = int(1) 1
    [1] = int(1) 2
    [2] = int(1) 3
    [3] = int(1) 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function merges(/*...*/){
    $args=func_get_args();
    $ret=array();
    foreach($args as $arg){
        foreach($arg as $key=>$v)
        {
            $ret[$key]=$v;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

untested, but i guess this would work.. will delete all duplicate keys and return the last key/value pair it found of duplicates

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for

```
$result = $a1 + $a2  //union operation
```

reference 
[Array Operations](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

Example

```
$a = array("a" => "apple", "b" => "banana");
$b = array("a" => "pear", "b" => "strawberry", "c" => "cherry");

$c = $a + $b; // Union of $a and $b
echo "Union of \$a and \$b: \n";
var_dump($c);
```

Ouput

```
Union of $a and $b:
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(5) "apple"
  ["b"]=>
  string(6) "banana"
  ["c"]=>
  string(6) "cherry"
}
```