# mysql_query UNION loop

Tags: mysql, loops, union

How I can do the same as in the script below using a loop?

```js
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table_1} WHERE txn_id LIKE '%{$txn_id}%'
     UNION
     SELECT * FROM {$table_2} WHERE txn_id LIKE '%{$txn_id}%'
     UNION
     SELECT * FROM {$table_3} WHERE txn_id LIKE '%{$txn_id}%'
     UNION
     SELECT * FROM {$table_4} WHERE txn_id LIKE '%{$txn_id}%'
     UNION
     SELECT * FROM {$table_5} WHERE txn_id LIKE '%{$txn_id}%'
```

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485242/set-theory-union-of-arrays-in-php for set unions in PHP.